# Получить рандомную строку из txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Задача: получить случайную строку из txt.
Как я вижу решение: при помощи `with open` открыть txt, далее прочитав его построчно, запихнуть все строки в список. После этого, при помощи `random.choice` выбрать случайную. Метод рабочий, но мне подсказывает интуиция, что на python можно сделать все лаконичнее и проще. 
Есть что-то такое? 
Пример моего кода:

```
import random
lines = []
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)
random_line = random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: `random.choice(file.readlines())` или `random.choice(list(file))` разве что.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать `readlines`, чтобы получить pythonic стиль кода:

```
import random
with open ('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```